# Why does the duration before the callback keep increasing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

In the process of toying with some jQuery animations, I've managed to get myself into a bit of a bind (where I can't use `.unbind()`).

I have a set of "inactive" blocks in `div#tray` that I would like to be able to swap with the "active" block in `div#main` by clicking on them. Animating the blocks out always happens immediately when I click them, but the more swaps I make, the longer it takes to get to the swap-and-animate-in function. Eventually it falls apart as steps apparently get skipped.

I don't understand why this is (some sort of timing problem?), so I've written a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JpUP4/) with my code, and would appreciate any insight.

Comment: I've discovered that the reason it's taking so long is that `swapBlocks` gets repeatedly called, but I don't know why it gets called more than once on later clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching the click events each time the animation ends. These just simply stack up and cause the slow down. The easiest way to solve this is to unbind all clicks before rebinding them.

```
function setupActiveBlockSwitcher() {
    $('.block').unbind('click');
    ...
```

This is a solution but its not that great, it would be better to reorganise your code so you don't have to rebind the events each time the animation finishes.

Comment: I ended up combining both answers into a solution: Reorganizing the code similar to Kolink's, but I thought your answer was clearest.

Answer (score 1):

I have [updated your code](http://jsfiddle.net/JpUP4/1/).

The main issue was that you were repeatedly assigning event handlers to the blocks, especially the ones that weren't being clicked in a given iteration.

With this updated code, I am applying a `click` handler to the container itself, and then using `event.target` to get the block that was actually clicked.

I have also removed the "set it up again" code from the animation function.